# Any path detecting between A to B

Tags: search-algorithms

In my world there are nodes and lines, I want to see if there is any path between node A, and node B, that do not cross any line(including the lines of the path itself) and do not go thru the same node twice. What would be the efficiency of such algorithm and where can I find more information about it.

So far I been reading about [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), but I do not need the shortest path, just to see if there is any path like this exist at all.

Comment: I think you need to give us more information about the problem, and maybe draw an example.  Why can't you build a graph, where the vertices are nodes, and there's an edge between node A and node B if you can get from node A to node B (without crossing any line)?  Then you should be able to compute reachability in this graph using any standard algorithm (e.g., depth-first search).

Comment: A* is a general algorithm, and it also needs a heuristic function. In particular cases you may be able to do with other algorithms - it all depends on the setting. I join D.W. in his query to not leave us in the dark.

Comment: Babibu, is the following question looking for the same thing you are looking for?    http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16269/755  Is that the same question, or is it different?  (That one is stated more precisely, so it'd be a great model to copy from.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***Depth-first search***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [***Breadth-first search***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Note that [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), essentially reduces to breadth-first-search with equal-cost-paths.

You can also do a sort of meet-in-the-middle (known as a [***bidirectional search***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search)), starting a search from both ends.

Any algorithm for detecting [***connected-components***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) will work here as well (again, these essentially using one of the search algorithms and adding connected nodes to some collection). However, you can perhaps use the some sort of [***disjoint-set-data-structure***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to keep track of different components as you add "lines" into the graph, and thus quickly test if the component of $A$ is the same as $B$. See also: [***connected-component labeling***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling), and [***partition refinement***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_refinement).

If your nodes have a special structure, you might be able to take advantage of it. For example, if you are thinking of nodes in euclidean space, you can use a [***spatial-index***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_index), such as a [***quad-tree***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), to speed the traversal/search by traversing whole globs of nodes in one shot when it is far from a line/obstacle. Another example would be to use [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*), even if you don't care about shortest-path, it might be better than simple breadth-first/depth-first, because of the structure and heuristic you can provide (see [best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) and [beam-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_search)).

**EDIT:**

I thought of another formulation of the problem (which likely would use one or a combination of the above approaches): [Is there an online-algorithm to keep track of components in a changing undirected graph](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2548/3377):

> - [Poly-Logarithmic Deterministic Fully-Dynamic Algorithms
>     for Connectivity, Minimum Spanning Tree, 2-Edge,
>     and Biconnectivit](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=502095) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.919&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).
> - [Near-optimal fully-dynamic graph connectivity](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=335345) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.5168&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

Comment: Aren't the worse case of all those is O(N!)

Comment: @Babibu no, [time complexity of BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Time_complexity) is $\mathcal{O}\left(|V|+|E|\right)$.

Comment: I don't understand how any of these can check whether a path crosses an edge in an embedding (which is what I think Babibu means by "intersection").

Comment: @G.Bach you don't allow the traversal/search to cross "dead" edges. Perhaps I am not understand your question, or his.

Comment: Oh, I missed that he doesn't want a shortest path, just any path will do. I assume by "dead" edges you mean those that intersect.

Comment: @G.Bach I assume he has a graph that has some edges which he doesn't want to cross ("lines"? or "lines" cross these edges?), and he wants to know if a path exists between A and B. So I simply say, remove those invalid edges from the graph, and do BFS or DFS. Not crossing the path itself is automatic, as shortest path takes care of that, and this is similar.

Comment: @RealzSlaw unfortunately I can't use it as is, as I want to prevent intersections with the path it self(the path that connecting between A,B), so basically I will need to add lines all the time. And this is what blowing up the performance.

Comment: @Babibu What do you mean by "intersection" in this question. What are "lines"?

Comment: @G.Bach line is the connection between two nodes. Intersection is when one line crossing another one.

Comment: @Babibu I thought you had a graph? The connection between two nodes is usually called an edge. A concept of "crossing" edges is not defined on graphs in general. Is your graph embedded?

Comment: @G.Bach I think he means a graph in the euclidean plane, with all nodes in the graph connected to eachother implicitly (like Euclidean TSP), and some blacklisted edges, so that his shortest-path/connectivity algorithm should not be allowed to use nor cross these edges. Babibu, can you confirm?

Comment: @RealzSlaw Confirmed!