# Shortest non intersecting path for a graph embedded in a euclidean plane (2D)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

What algorithm would you use to find the shortest path of a graph, which is embedded in an euclidean plane, such that the path should not contain any self-intersections (in the embedding)?

For example, in the graph below, you want to go from $(0,0) \rightarrow (-3,2)$. Normally, an algorithm like Dijkstra's algorithm would produce a sequence like:

$$\left[ (0,0) \stackrel {3}{\rightarrow} (0,3) \stackrel{\sqrt{2}}{\rightarrow} (1,2) \stackrel{4}{\rightarrow} (-3,2) \right] = 7+\sqrt{2}.$$

Full graph:

[image]

Shortest path:

[image]

Shortest non-intersecting path:

[image]

However, this path intersects itself on the euclidean plane, therefore I *want* an algorithm that would give me the shortest non-intersecting sequence, in this case:

$$\left[(0,0) \stackrel{3}{\rightarrow} (0,3) \stackrel{3}{\rightarrow} (0,6) \stackrel{5}{\rightarrow} (-3,2) \right] = 11.$$

This path is longer than the shortest path, but it is the shortest non-intersecting path.

**Is there an (efficient) algorithm that can do this?**

### TikZ sources

- [Full graph](https://www.writelatex.com/read/jzkhmqgmqcnj).
- [Shortest path](https://www.writelatex.com/read/kwpwzzcfyjcy).
- [Shortest non-intersecting path](https://www.writelatex.com/read/qzrbvwxgpbtp).

Comment: Nice problem!  (+1).  Can you say anything about the application or context where this problem arises?  I'm intrigued.  (P.S. On a separate note: The obvious way out of this conundrum is to see if you can introduce a new vertex for every intersection point, i.e., every point where one edge can intersect another edge.  However I realize that for some/many applications this might not be possible.)

Comment: @D.W. this is me reformulating Babibu's ill-worded [burning donkey/pony problem](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16259/2755); the application is his Euclidean TSP heuristic algorithm, I am not exactly sure how he intends to use it, but I imagine he wants to know if he can find a path between two points, when he already visited several others (Euclidean TSP's optimal tour will be non-intersecting). And yes, if you can introduce new nodes, that would be great, but the question is if you can't (and ofc you can't introduce new cities for Euclidean TSP).

Comment: Let me try to convert the path existence problem to 3SAT. Making a way to cross two signals while not crossing two paths seems the biggest challenge.

Comment: Yep. Clearly NP-complete. Gathering evidence.

Comment: @JanDvorak converting to SAT makes it in NP; to prove it is NP-complete, you would have to convert SAT to this problem. Not sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: Yep. I meant solving SAT through this.

Comment: strong suspicion this has been studied or solved in the literature. see eg this survey [crossing number of graphs](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-03456-5_21) by Mutzel. seems to date as early as Turan 1944.

Comment: @vzn I can't see how the crossing number problem relates to the non-crossing path existence or length. In the crossing number problem, the amount of crossings is minimised by choosing the embedding. Here, the embedding is given and the goal is to pick a subset of the edges.

Comment: @jan isnt it true that graphs with no crossings are those with minimal crossings?

Comment: If what you mean is that in planar graphs every path is a non-crossing path, then this is a trivial result. If what you mean is that every path by itself is a planar graph, then this is equally trivial.

Comment: @jan am just proposing an apparent connection. am not enough of an expert to nail down exact details at this pt. the main point is that nobody [else] has made any effort to tie this question into the known scientific literature. do you really believe this is a novel problem which has no connection? find that position questionable itself & dubious. this site is for computer **science**....

Comment: @vzn No. That is not my belief. I'm not convinced in either way. I am not sure this is a novel problem, and I'm not convinced it's a problem that has been solved (or discussed) before. What I did suggest, however, is that _that specific resource_ that you have offered does not seem to me to be related to the problem presented here. If I am mistaken in this specific point - it could well be - then I will appreciate to be shown a specific connection between the crossing number of a graph and the existence or length of the shortest non-crossing path in a graph embedding. I did read the abstract.

Comment: @jan ok! fair enough. meanwhile, wondering, what is the proof that the solution to this problem is not a solution to 2d TSP?

Comment: @vzn not even this is a claim I have made, but: 1) The decision version of TSP is in NP, and this problem is NP-complete. Thus, it is possible to convert an instance of euclidean TSP to this problem (just not using the same graph). 2) If a graph has a hamiltonian path of length l, then the shortest path between any two vertices is at most that long. A solution to eTSP is never self-crossing. 3) The complete graph has a non-intersecting path under any embedding. If the graph is not complete, then the shortest hamiltonian cycle may be self-crossing (ex: square graph under its bowtie embedding).

Comment: @jan dont quite understand why you say "not using the same graph". am saying it seems like the optimal solution to the above problem could be nearly a solution to 2d TSP on the same graph and dont see a way to immediately disprove it. that would not be surprising because the above problem arose/originated in the study of finding heuristics to solve TSP. maybe am misunderstanding the above problem. seems nearly equivalent to, given a set of 2d coordinates, find a minimal non-crossing cycle?

Comment: @vzn uhh... the shortest path between two vertices almost never leads through all other vertices. The shortest non-intersecting path is usually not a solution to TSP

Comment: @jan the above question is nearly equivalent to asking for a cycle, it is just asking for a path between all vertices right? ie only 1 less edge than a full cycle through all pts... if the start/end pts of the shortest path end up close together, it is nearly equivalent to 2d TSP...

Comment: @vzn negative. This question requests the shortest non-itersecting path betweeen two vertices without requiring any other vertex to be visited. Not even the example shortest path visits every vertex - the far east vertex stays unvisited. The problem this question is based on is unclear. The TSP appears to be present in the back story, but then the actual problem appears to devolve into an instance of any-non-intersecting-path problem (NP-C as I proved) or maybe the any-non-intersecting-hamiltonian-path problem (which appears to be NP-C as well).

Comment: @jan oops, ok agreed, thx for clarification, read it more carefully, got mixed up by a diagram, thought it was talking about a path visiting all vertices. but wait, are you saying the above problem might have some relationship to nonintersecting hamiltonian path? dont see that now... the case that seems similar is if a minimal path also visits all vertices, agreed this is not guaranteed in general...

Comment: asked similar question for [$n$-point paths/cycles & its relation to TSP](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19553/attacking-tsp-via-small-nonintersecting-circuits), tcs.se

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is NP-complete to even decide whether *any* path exists.

It is clearly possible to verify any given path is a valid path in the given graph. Thus the bounded-length problem is in NP, and so is its subset, the any-path problem.

Now, to prove NP-hardness of the any-path problem (and thus of the bounded-length problem), let's reduce SAT-CNF to this problem:

---

**The global structure** is a grid of wire pieces adjoined by a column of clause pieces. Logic formula is satisfiable iff there exists a non-intersecting path through the graph.

It is impossible to cross two pieces of the path, but it is neccessary to cross two logic wires. Rather, the path flow is strictly given: a wire point is given by two nodes. The sequence of the wire points through which the path passes is forced by the reduction. Logic is represented by which node is chosen. Any path can be chosen as long as it passes through all wire points.

In this diagram, the path is represented by the red curve and the logic flow is represented by the black wires:

[image: grid of wires on the left, column of clause pieces on the right.]

Now let's build each component.

---

Wiring uses three tiles: the crossing, the branch point, and the vertical wire. Let's start with the hardest one:

The basic idea behind **the crossing** is to prepare a path for each pair of wire points and bend the possible paths enough so that all pairs except those that encode the same logic (compatible paths) cross each other. Of course we can't just say two parallel edges intersect, but we can introduce extra order-2 nodes to make two paths intersect.

Supposing the paths come from north to west and from south to east, we can: collect each path from north with its compatible path from east on a line (some incompatible paths will cross each other); cross each pair with each other by reversing the order of pairs; distribute the paths to their south and west endpoints. This is best explained by a diagram. Here, each pair of nodes represents a wire point. Paths with the same color code (carrying the same logic) don't intersect, paths a different color code do:

[image: graphical depiction of the above]

**The branch point** and **the vertical wire** work the same, but there are fewer paths to correlate:

[image: two pairs of paths are sufficient here. The wire is essentially a branch point with the branch destroyed]

**The clause box** follows the same logic: each literal exposes one of its paths to the reading wire, then converging to the south (if it's the northernmost term or the term to the north converges to the north) or to the north (if the term to the north converges to the south). The reading wire (one node at the endpoints) branches to become one path per literal. Each reading path then crosses the literal's true-path if the literal is negated, the false-path if it is not. Note that the converged path may or may not cross a clause boundary. For consistency, here's a diagram for $\neg A \vee \neg B$:

[image]

It is possible to generalise this reduction to encode an arbitrary tree of AND and OR gates by branching the reading wire in different way. In particular, SAT-CNF and SAT-DNF are both possible to reduce to the non-intersecting path problem in the way described as above.

Comment: Wow, well done man. I haven't reviewed it yet, but the work you put in is amazing.

Comment: OK, I just want to summarize my understanding: using the first gadget, one can cross any two literal-path pairs and maintain the paths used. Therefore, one doesn't have to worry about planarity for laying out the paths (like the xor gadget in PlanarCircuitSat does for circuits). Then using the final gadget, one can create arbitrary logical clauses (no longer having to worry about planarity). Is this correct?

Comment: This seems correct but you have to ensure two things for a general layout: That you are able to power all gadgets with an NIP path (this should always be possible - if a path becomes stuck in the center, you can introduce wire-gadgets to bring lone ends of the path together) and that all paths in the reading wire cross each other in such a way that it is not possible to reverse within the wire (it seems to me that it is guaranteed if there are no true-clauses (not crossing any literal) and if all clauses are on the outside of the circuit (on the same face the start and end are)).

Comment: ensuring that all paths in the reading wire cross each other is easy - if you want to be sure, just branch off n paths, then cross all of them right away. I think this is never neccessary, however.

Comment: Just curious, what did you use to draw the diagrams?

Comment: I used OpenOffice Draw for the global structure, and [yEd](www.yworks.com/products/yed) for the rest. Should I edit that in (with `<sub>`)?

Comment: Thanks. No need, its cool. Nice drawing :D

Answer (score -1):

the problem seems to date to Turan 1944. this looks like a good survey of theory and algorithms, [the Crossing Number of Graphs: Theory and Computation](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-03456-5_21) by Mutzel. wikipedia has some info under [crossing number of graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29)

Comment: Maybe this is better as a comment?

Comment: it scientifically answers the basic question "what algorithm would you use"

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: jan cites a ref from stackexchange meta. while thats a valid idea, the role of citations in science/mathematics is different than a programming tips site.... [admittedly the ref is not available to me currently for a more detailed answer].. anyway it is quite possible something like jans construction, while useful/worthwhile, is already in the literature and in science, its part of the standard process/best practices to [attempt to] locate it....